# basic check box in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started to learn React and trying to make very simple check box component and getting error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null**  which i could not figure out why i am getting so can any one please help me?

```
<div id="react-container">
    </div>
    <script   type="text/babel">

    class Checkedbox extends React.Component{
        initialState(){
          return { checked: false }
        };
        handelCheck(){
            this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked })
        };
        render(){
            var msg ;
            if(this.state.checked){
                 msg = 'Agree';
            } else {
                 msg = 'Disagree';
            }
            return (
                   <div>
                       <label for="mybox"> Opinion : </label>
                       <input type="checkbox"  id="mybox" onChange={this.handleCheck}
                              defaultChecked={this.state.checked}/>
                       <p>Hi i {msg} with it!</p>
                   </div>
            )
        };
    }
    let target = document.getElementById('react-container');
    ReactDOM.render(   < Checkedbox />,target)
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onChange={this.handleCheck}
```

change to

```
onChange={this.handleCheck.bind(this)}
```

Answer (score 0):

change initialState() to getInitialState().

Comment: yes i changed and got a warning message "getInitialState was defined on Checkedbox, a plain JavaScript class. This is only supported for classes created using React.createClass."  and still same error message too.

Comment: Are you requiring React and ReactDOM properly?

Comment: Care for a reference, like a documentation explaining the difference?

Answer (score 0):

I guess `this` doesn't belong to the actual element:

```
handelCheck(){
    let that = this;
    this.setState({checked: !that.state.checked })
};
```

Comment: same warning and error message. Can we use getInitialState() even if we declare  a component with **class** syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It should work

```
class Checkedbox extends React.Component{
            constructor(){
              super();
              this.state = { checked: false }
            }
            handleCheck = () => {
                this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked })
            }
            render(){
                var msg ;
                if(this.state.checked){
                     msg = 'Agree';
                } else {
                     msg = 'Disagree';
                }
                return (
                       <div>
                           <label for="mybox"> Opinion : </label>
                           <input type="checkbox"  id="mybox" onChange={this.handleCheck}
                                  defaultChecked={this.state.checked}/>
                           <p>Hi i {msg} with it!</p>
                       </div>
                )
            };
        }
        let target = document.getElementById('react-container');
        ReactDOM.render(   < Checkedbox />,target)
```